# How to put dhtmlx popup with user input controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I want to put dhtmlx popup with textboxes and button onto the popup window in my html form using jquery. How can I do it?

Comment: do you want a form inside a popup?

Comment: @Moazzam Khan -yes I want a form inside popup window.

Comment: @VAGABOND-Currently I am using a seprate div.I have search in dhtmlx popup but could not find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use jQuery then [jQuery Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) is  your guy.